# Reading token with slimframework

Tags: access-token, slim

I'm using SlimFramework and JWT to handle token based authentication with login and password.

I managed to login and send token in response.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());

$app->post('/auth/login', function () use ($app) {
    $params = $app->request()->getBody();
    if ($params['email'] == "login" && $params['password'] == "password") {
        $key = "example_key";
        $token = array(
            "id" => "1",
            "exp" => time() + (60 * 60 * 24)
        );
        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);
        $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("token" => $jwt));
    }
});

$app->get("/user", function () {
    echo "ok";
});
$app->run();
```

1. How to check token in `/user` path?
   Making `/user` request I'm sending header with `Authorization:Bearer eHrR....`
2. And just for clearing - is that kind of auth (login and password) and OAuth the same?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [JSON Web Token Authentication middleware](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth). Install latest version using composer.

```
$ composer require tuupola/slim-jwt-auth
```

Also add the following to the `.htaccess file`. Otherwise PHP wont have access to the `Authorization: Bearer` header.

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Then add the middleware to the Slim application. When request is made middleware tries to validate and decode the token. If token is not found server will response with `401 Unauthorized`. If token exists but there is an error when validating and decoding it server will response with `400 Bad Request`.

In the callback function middleware stores the content of token to `$app->jwt`. You can access this later in other routes.

```php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => "your_example_key",
    "callback" => function ($options) use ($app) {
        $app->jwt = $options["decoded"];
    }
]));

$app->get("/user", function () {
    print_r($app->jwt);
});

$app->run();
```