# Many AJAX requests at once with CSRF protection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csrf, slim

**Hi everybody.**

My web application is based on asynchronous requests. Timer widget is working and updating it's status every second by AJAX (yes, it is necessary).

**I am sending with each AJAX my CSRF tokens:**

```
project_data.append(csrf_name_key,csrf_name_value);
project_data.append(csrf_value_key,csrf_value_value);
```

**And in response I am updating that global variables:**

```
function setCSRF(response) {
    csrf_name_key = response.nameKey;
    csrf_name_value = response.name;
    csrf_value_key = response.valueKey;
    csrf_value_value = response.value;      
}
```

Everything is generally fine. But if I will do another AJAX for example when I change task in todo list to "done" it sometimes ending with error because I am sending AJAX before I am getting new tokens from previous request.

I really don't know how to do solve that problem. First idea was that I will make "like stack array" with 5 different tokens but one https request = one pair of tokens and I can't generate it.

Maybe some type of queue of ajax requests, but what with doing them in a right time - I don't know.

**My actual pseudo-solution is "if failed try again max 10 times":**

```
if(e.target.response=="Failed CSRF check!") {
    if(failedAjax<10) checkForSurvey();
    failedAjax++;
    return;
}
```

It is generally working, but errors are appears in a console and it is very dirty solution.

I am using Slim 3 microframework with CSRF extension. Really please for help with that interesting problem.

**I will be very thankful,**

Arthur

Comment: I would give each action (timer, update todo, etc.) its own csrf token.

Comment: But for generate token you need to make http request. For make that request you need to pass actual tokes or wait - maybe I will off CSRF protection for "token generator" route? Is this a save solution?

Comment: Can't you send the initial tokens on page load?

Comment: I can and I am doing it actually. But I cant generate 5 other tokens on page load. CSRF generating function is getting request as parameter and gives 5 same tokens.

Comment: So add the action that the token is valid for to the request parameter.

Comment: The approach may you take as you can create an CSRF token array per session base and then check a incoming token is present in the array or not. If yes then you can validate the request else not, and fire another ajax  at every minute which will delete the old csrf token from the array. But as I don't know the slim framework, so I can't suggest how can you hack slim to implement this. I hope this may serve your purpose

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar But in your solution somebody will use http request link on his site, and when user is on that site, that link is running script and CSRF check think everything is great because tokens are in session?

Comment: Then you should use the CSRF Token to request a new array of csrf tokens, as said by @AbhisekMalakar
If you don't worry about performance you could make the ajax request wait untill a new CSRF tokens arrives.

Comment: @Edenwave when the request link will be triggered from another site, then from another site the session will not be same. As session cookie must differ, so it will keep you away from the fear of CSRF hijack. Be assured, though the user is logged on your site, until the session is hijacked no can beat this CSRF protection technique by just hitting the your reqeust end point from another website. Hope it clear the confusion

Comment: But how can I generate 5 other tokens when function generating that tokens uses same $request and genrate SAME 5 tokens, not different?

Comment: @Jeroen How would you like to give other CSRF to each action? I need to generate it on page load but its imposible to generate more then one token.

Comment: @Eaton Emmerich But it is imposible to generat emore then one token on page load.

Comment: `and updating it's status every second by AJAX ` is this only a get request or, does this change something on serverside?

Comment: @jmattheis It is updating some informations of timer in DB and getting new tokens generated from that request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some options for you:

1. Use a stack of csrf-tokens inside you javascript code
2. Use a csrf token which is can be used more than once (not so secure)
3. Use a queue for the request

#### A stack for the tokens

The `Slim-Csrf`-middleware provides functionallity for you, to generate these tokens, you just need to get them to the clientside.
You could do an api for getting 5 csrf tokens, this api would also consume on csrf-token.

Add an api and generate the tokens there.

```
$app->get('/foo', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // check valid  csrf token

    $tokens = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        $tokens[] = $this->csrf->generateToken();
    }

    return $response->withJson($tokens);
});
```

Now the csrf-token are valid through the whole user session.

`Guard::generateToken()` returns something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  'csrf_name' => string 'csrf58e669ff70da0' (length=17)
  'csrf_value' => string '52ac7689d3c6ea5d01889d711018f058' (length=32)
```

#### A multi-use csrf-token

For that, Slim-Csrf already provides functionallity with the token persistance mode. That can be enabled through the constructor or the `Guard::setPersistentTokenMode(bool)` method. In my example, I'm doing this with the method:

```
$container['csrf'] = function ($c) {
    $guard = new \Slim\Csrf\Guard;
    $guard->setPersistentTokenMode(true);
    return $guard;
};
```

Here the PhpDoc from the `persistanceTokenMode`-attribute

```
/**
 * Determines whether or not we should persist the token throughout the duration of the user's session.
 *
 * For security, Slim-Csrf will *always* reset the token if there is a validation error.
 * @var bool True to use the same token throughout the session (unless there is a validation error),
 * false to get a new token with each request.
 */
```

#### A queue for the ajax requests.

Add a queue for the request, that could be delay the execution of your request but there will always be a valid csrf token.

This should be seen as pseudocode as I havn't tested this yet.

```
var requestQueue = [];
var isInRequest = false;

var csrfKey = ''; // should be set on page load, to have a valid token at the start
var csrfValue = '';

function newRequest(onSuccessCallback, data) { // add all parameters you need
    // add request to the queue
    requestQueue.push(function() {
        isInRequest = true;
        // add to csrf stuff to data
        $.ajax({
            data: xxx
            url: "serverscript.xxx",
            success: function(data) {
                // update csrfKey & csrfValue
                isInRequest = false;
                tryExecuteNextRequest(); // try execute next request
                onSuccessCallback(data); // proceed received data
            }
        }});
    );
    tryExecuteNextRequest();
}

function tryExecuteNextRequest() {
    if(!isInRequest && requestQueue.length != 0) { // currently no request running &
        var nextRequest = requestQueue.shift();
        nextRequest(); // execute next request
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I used a stack :) I tought that I can't generate more then one token on page load :C But everything is fine I am using 5 tokens array in js :)

Comment: Hello again. That for loop is returning tokens with same name and other values and csrf is taking last defined token as right, others are not valid and system returns failed csrf check... Is that any way to generate 5 other and valid tokens from one request?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can simply eliminate CSRF by not accepting cookies for authentication.

You can save the authentication token in the localStorage and send it as an header with each request.

This way you'll never need to worry about CSRF and its tokens.

Comment: Can you explain it more? I think in your solution CSRF is just going to not checking tokens and open my application for cross-site attacks :)

Comment: CSRF is based on the fact that the browser automatically sends cookies with every request. If the website is using cookies for authentication than an attacker can lead a user to his own website and do something like this:
<img src="https://example.com/send-money?amount=1000&to=123/>
This request will be accepted as if the user initiated it, the auth cookie is being sent to the server.
If that website would not accept that auth cookie and instead will use a header for authentication - that attack vector and all CSRF attacks would not work.

Comment: Ok, I understand it more now but not in 100% :C. How it would like to look in the practise? How to not accept that cookies?

Comment: I don't know much about slim, but there is probably a way to eliminate auth cookies in its configuration.
You may want to consider using JWT for token authentication. Slim seems to support it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379936/reading-token-with-slimframework
http://discourse.slimframework.com/t/slim-3-with-json-web-token/209

Comment: You can also check for it manually with something like:
if(isset($req->headers('X-Auth-Token')) {
 //authenticateWithToken
} else {
 //go away
}

Sorry for my poor PHP skills.